# Insert and select in node loop not working

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm calling two functions, where first function is inserting the data in the table. I'm using `mysql`. The second one is count the value of the and display it.

The problem is, the second function is processing before inserting the table. What i'm doing wrong?.

My code is:

```
function_my(id);
console.log('id inserted');
count(id);

function_my(id){
  var mysql = require('mysql2');  
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'gcm',
  }); 
  for(var id=0; j < 10; j++){
    connection.query('INSERT INTO UserTable SET ?', {id : id}, function(err, res){
                if(err) throw err;
    });
}

count(id){
    connection.execute('select id from UserTable where id = ?', id , function(err, rows){
        console.log('Test :'+JSON.stringify(rows[0].id));
    });
}
```

the output is:

```
Test : undefined
Id inserted
```

why i'm facing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `count` function after `insert` operation.
`count(id)`  should be used as the callback function, after all the records are inserted.

You may need to look into some `Promise` libraries (like `bluebird`) for more information.